# Microsoft SQL Server Native Client Scuppered by PRINT statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I am calling SQL Server Stored Procedures from Classic ASP using "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0".  I've been doing so for years.  I've just developed a Stored Procedure that makes use of PRINT statements to provide informative messages during development and also when called from MSSMS.  However, when I call the same Stored Procedure from Classic ASP via SQL Server Native Client, I get an 0x80040e14 error with the text from the first PRINT statement appearing in the error code.

I've googled for the issue but can't find anywhere where it says you cannot do this, so I am wondering if I am missing a trick somewhere.  Can anyone point me to evidence that I can't include PRINT statements (boo!) or if I'm doing something silly?

**The Exception:**

> Unhandled exception at line 71, column 3 in
>   http ://localhost:3000/DataAccess/Workpalces.asp
>
> 0x80040e14 - Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0: ---- START Assessment.RefreshUP ----

**My (abridged) Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Assessment.RefreshUP 
    @OrgID int, 
    @UserID int = NULL,
    @BaseDate smalldatetime = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @Error             int
    DECLARE @RowCount          int
    BEGIN TRY
        PRINT '---- START Assessment.RefreshUP ----'
        (snip)
```

**My Classic ASP Call:**

```vb
' Assessment.RefreshUP
' ========================
' Creates or updates a Workplace
Function Assessment_RefreshUP(rs, OrganisationID, UserID)
    Stop
    Dim cmd
    Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = DBConnString
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "Assessment.RefreshUP"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@OrgID",    adInteger, adParamInput, 0, OrganisationID)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@UserID",   adInteger, adParamInput, 0, UserID)
'   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@BaseDate", adDate,    adParamInput, 0, Null)
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClientBatch
    rs.Open cmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Could you post your full stored procedure, got the feeling your `PRINT` isn't the issue. It appears in the exception is happening afterward as the error code refers to `Unclosed quotation mark after the character string`. As your `PRINT` statement outputs doubt this is the issue.

Comment: I suspect you are right as I've just stumbled upon a different ASP/Stored Procedure call which has PRINT statements in them but are not affecting them.  Should I edit my original post or add the full Stored Procedure in a comment?

Comment: Just edit your existing post extend your stored procedure code, you can leave an edit at the bottom of your post to say you have updated it but to be honest people will know. ;)

Comment: OK.  The message text in the Exception was a red herring: I've set my @debug parameter back to 1 and it still works.  I however was able to recreate the problem (including the error message text in the exception) by referencing a User Defined Function that didn't exist further down in my Stored Procedure:

Comment: Should have paid more attention to your post before answering glad you managed to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem can be found by looking at the Exception Code (0x80040e14) and NOT relying on the Exception Text ("---- START Assessment.RefreshUP ----").

In my case, the problem was a call to a User Defined Function (UDF) further down in the Stored Procedure that didn't exist.  However the presence of the PRINT statement has affected the Exception "text" and led me down the wrong path.

You CAN have PRINT statements in Stored Procedures which are called from Classic ASP / SQL Server Native Client.

If you encounter the problem, do try calling your Stored Procedure directly from MSSMS, ideally using the SQL captured from SQL Profiler in order to determine the true source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`PRINT` statements are great for debugging purposes but having encountered these issues I found having an extra parameter something like `@debug TINYINT = 0` in your stored procedure was useful for not displaying `PRINT` statements or debug output of any kind by default, but allowing you to switch it on when you wanted to debug the procedure.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE Assessment.RefreshUP 
  @OrgID int, 
  @UserID int = NULL,
  @BaseDate smalldatetime = NULL,
  @Debug tinyint = 0
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  DECLARE @Error             int
  DECLARE @RowCount          int
  BEGIN TRY
    IF (@debug = 1) PRINT '---- START Assessment.RefreshUP ----'
    (snip)
```

In some cases also prefer the use of `RAISERROR` as it allows you to pass multiple parameters like the way `String.Format()` works in .Net.

[RAISERROR...WITH NOWAIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Lankymart.  I suspected adding a debug parameter might be a "best workaround" solution.  I'm just surprised I've not been able to google other people's experience of this problem, nor found any documentation that clearly states that PRINT or RAISERROR statements cannot be used.